# How to concat multiple fields in mongoose query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to find() all docs with LIKE 'query.name' in concatenated fields instead of using $or to search in separated ones.

SQL query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column.name + ' ' + column.surname LIKE query.name
```

This is the current code:

```
Model.find()
.and([
  {
    $or: [
      { name: new RegExp(req.query.name, 'i') },
      { surname: new RegExp(req.query.name, 'i') }
    ]
  },
  {
    $or: [
      { workPlace: new RegExp(req.query.place, 'i') },
      { location: new RegExp(req.query.place, 'i') }
    ]
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved in a two stage aggregation query: The idea is to concatenate [`$concat`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) the name and location fields as separate filter attributes in the first stage using [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) and then search using [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) and [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) in the next stage.

Example:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      nameFilter: {
        $concat: ["$name", " ", "$surname"],
      },
      locationFilter: {
        $concat: ["$workplace", " ", "$location"],
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      nameFilter: {
        $regex: req.query.name,
        $options: "i",
      },
      locationFilter: {
        $regex: req.query.place,
        $options: "i",
      },
    },
  },
]);
```

[mongo playground example link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wXAtMyX2K9i)

Answer (score -1):

You should read about Mongoose virtuals [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals)
Example

```
  var personSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
      first: String,
      last: String
    }
  });

  // compile our model
  var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);

  // create a document
  var axl = new Person({
    name: { first: 'Axl', last: 'Rose' }
  });
```

In your case schema could be something like this

```
var studentSchema = newSchema ({
student: {
   name : String,
   surname : String,
   worplace : String,
   location : STring
})
```

After this,just follow the steps from the link I gave you.

Comment: you cannot query Mongoose Virtuals unfortunately. for this to work, you'd have to get ALL the entries and compare them to the Virtual which could be extremely inefficient.